# php's call_user_func with variable do not work

Tags: php, oop, variables

I try to call objects methods dynamically  but do not get it to work

```
the not working case
$method = 'my_function';
$target_xml = call_user_func(array($api, $method));

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method
```

if I var_dump(array($api, $method))

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(APIModel)[12]
      private 'client' => null
      private 'affiliate' => null
      private 'prod_category' => null
      protected 'viewModel' => 
        object(ViewModel)[13]
      protected 'db' => 
        object(MysqliDb)[14]
          protected '_mysqli' => 
            object(mysqli)[15]
              public 'affected_rows' => null
              public 'client_info' => null
              public 'client_version' => null
              public 'connect_errno' => null
              public 'connect_error' => null
              public 'errno' => null
              public 'error' => null
              public 'error_list' => null
              public 'field_count' => null
              public 'host_info' => null
              public 'info' => null
              public 'insert_id' => null
              public 'server_info' => null
              public 'server_version' => null
              public 'stat' => null
              public 'sqlstate' => null
              public 'protocol_version' => null
              public 'thread_id' => null
              public 'warning_count' => null
          protected '_query' => null
          protected '_join' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          protected '_where' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          protected '_whereTypeList' => null
          protected '_orderBy' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          protected '_groupBy' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          protected '_paramTypeList' => null
          protected '_bindParams' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[16]
      string 'my_function' (length=5)
```

**working case**

```
$target_xml = call_user_func(array($api, 'my_function'));
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(array($api, $method));` show you?  Maybe there's some extra (unprintable) character in there?

Comment: `object(SimpleXMLElement)` does not seem suspicious to you...?

Comment: (string) fixed the problem

Answer (score -2):

Proper usage:

```
$target_xml = call_user_func('my_function', array($api));
```

Comment: It isn't proper usage. It's incorrect: no method specified

Comment: The OP is trying the equivalent of `$api->my_function()`, not `my_function(array($api))`.

Comment: Then try to:

$api->{$method}();